# Nest.JS token providers

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to provide a token to my module. The module looks like this:

```
@Module({
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  exports: [AuthGuard],
})
export class AuthGuardModule {
  public static forRoot(
    configProvider: Provider<IGuardConfigToken>
  ): DynamicModule {
    return {
      providers: [configProvider],
      module: AuthGuardModule,
    };
  }
}
```

The parent module into which I import AuthGuardModule looks like this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TokenDataAccessModule,
    AuthGuardModule.forRoot(guardConfigProvider),
  ],
  controllers: [CompanyController],
})
export class CompanyModule {}
```

And the guardConfigProvider itself looks like this:

```
export const guardConfigProvider: FactoryProvider<IGuardConfigToken> = {
  provide: GUARD_CONFIG_TOKEN,
  useFactory: (tokenService: TokenService): IGuardConfigToken => ({
    validateToken: tokenService.validateToken.bind(tokenService),
  }),
  inject: [TokenService],
};
```

But I get an error:
`ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the GUARD_CONFIG_TOKEN (?). Please make sure that the argument TokenService at index [0] is available in the AuthGuardModule context.`

TokenService is located in the TokenDataAccessModule provider and is exported there. I don't understand why this error occurs in this case.

It seems that in the example above the provisioning should work, but it doesn’t

Answer (score 0):

Because `AuthGuardModule` has the `provider`

```js
{
  provide: GUARD_CONFIG_TOKEN,
  useFactory: (tokenService: TokenService): IGuardConfigToken => ({
    validateToken: tokenService.validateToken.bind(tokenService),
  }),
  inject: [TokenService],
}
```

the `inject` tells Nest that there needs to be access to the`TokenService` provider in the `AuthGuardModule`. Adding the `TokenDataAccessModule` to the `imports` array of the dynamic module for the `AuthGuardModule` will resolve the issue for you.

Comment: If I add a TokenDataAccessModule to the AuthGuardModule, then the meaning of my token is lost. In AuthGuardModule I would like to use only GUARD_CONFIG_TOKEN

Comment: But your `GUARD_CONFIG_TOKEN` relies on `TokenService` so wherever you create the `GUARD_CONFIG_TOKEN` provider, you need to have access to `TokenService` and for that you need to import `TokenDataAccessModule`, that's literally how Nest's modules and providers work

Comment: What's the point of creating tokens then if I can't use dependencies on the modules on top? Doesn't nest.js have a tree of injectors like Angular?

Comment: Providers don't traverse "top-down", they traverse through the `imports` of a module, "up" the chain so to speak.

Comment: If we imagine that AuthGuardModule is a module from a third-party library, for its correct operation you need to provide the GUARD_CONFIG_TOKEN token with the validateToken method. How can I do that?

Comment: If it's definition comes from another module, like it does for you, usually there's a `forRootAsync` you'd make use of where you can define a `useFactory` that can _also_ use an `imports` to say what module the provider config should come from

Comment: Isn't this what happens in my case? CompanyModule imports a TokenDataAccessModule with a provider for TokenService, as well as an AuthGuardModule in forRoot which passes a provider for GUARD_CONFIG_TOKEN.
As far as I understand, in this case, there is a TokenService in CompanyModule, which should be transferred to guardConfigProvider, right?

Comment: Nope, because the `GUARD_CONFIG_TOKEN` provider belongs to the `AuthGuardModule`, not the `CompanyModule` where the access to `TokenService` is. You'd need to tell `AuthGuardModule` about the import to `TokenDataAccessModule` so that the `GUARD_CONFIG_TOKEN`'s dependencies are resolvable.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this can be done without mentioning the TokenService/TokenDataAccessModule in the AuthGuardModule. Well, the question arises about the tree of injectors. If AuthGuardModule can't find the TokenService dependency within itself, shouldn't it go up the chain to CompanyModule and grab it there?

Comment: No, because the `AuthGuardModule` must be created before the `CompanyModule` is created. Like I said, providers travel "up" through the `imports` array, not by why defined the import of the module (i.e. from `AuthGuardModule` _to_ `CompanyModule`, not the other way around)

Comment: In that case, as far as I understand, if I add the @Global decorator to the TokenDataAccessModule or import it in, say, the appModule, then it should work. But it doesn't work

Comment: Adding `@Global()` to `TokenDataAccessModule` should work. Adding it to `AppModule's` imports without that global shouldn't though